# Ubuntu SSH connection error

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I install ssh in ubuntu.I configured it.When I tried to connect using

`$ssh user@192.168.1.67`
It ask password. I never mention password while installing it and in config file also. What password should I enter? 
I also tried by changing config file I set `PasswordAuthentication no` then it gives me error that Permission denied(Publickey).

Comment: show us what pubkey you configured.

Comment: While this is not an entirely appropriate question for a forum about programming, the password that ssh expects is the account password for 'user' on 192.168.1.67 (the one you would use to log in as 'user' or to run `sudo`). I am also assuming that you have installed an ssh daemon on 192.168.1.67, otherwise it would simply refuse the connection. Finally, no-password authentication requires a careful setup of a public and private keys. If this is what you want to do, check out the discussion at http://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter the account password for which you want to log in. For example the user in the system is abc, then the password will be the password for the user 'abc. And you need to user

`ssh abc@ip`

and then you need to enter the password for the account abc.